# How to get data from google chrome using vba

Tags: vba

In one of my requirement i have to open one internal website and pull the data from that page. But the website has some limitations that it will open in Chrome only. I have experience in automating IE, I tried the same way of creating object for Chrome.

```
Set CHromeapp = CreateObject("Chrome.Application")
```

But its throwing error as "activex component can't create object". Can any one help me to create an object and navigate to Chrome.

Comment: What happens if you try to open the website with IE

Answer (score 2):

Google Chrome is not a .NET application, therefore you cant create a VBA object.

Answer (score -1):

Sub test544()

Dim chromePath As String

chromePath = """C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"""
  Shell (chromePath & " https://www.oanda.com/currency/converter/")

End Sub

Comment: This works fine

Comment: Explain your answer.